# Customer Backend Fax option not displaying

Tags: magento2, admin, customer, backend

**In Magento 2 Community edition**,

**Fax attribute** is not displaying in customer and there is no option to enable it. Can anybody help me How to display FAX in create customer form backend ?

Comment: Anybody have update on this? I am still looking for solution.

Comment: Have you found any solutions for fax attribute?